# strange Gurobi error when running Snakemake

Tags: snakemake, gurobi

I just installed Snakemake (with sudo) on a shared system, and when I run it, even `snakemake --version`, I get the strange error:

```
murray@alina:~$ snakemake --version
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pulp/apis/gurobi_api.py:297: UserWarning: GUROBI error:
ERROR 10009: No Gurobi license found (user murray, host alina, hostid da781c18, cores 64)

.
  warnings.warn('GUROBI error: {}.'.format(out))
5.31.1
```

I understand that this error is related to licensing issues with the Gurobi solver (or at least its API), that is installed on the system, however, why should running Snakemake elicit this error?  Fixing this, or even just squelching the error (and the resulting `gurobi.log` file which gets created in the directory where the `snakemake --version` command is run) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Strange... How did you install snakemake?

Comment: It looks like snakemake is calling PuLP, which calls Gurobi. I'm not familiar with snakemake but you should look to configure it without PuLP unless you need that feature.

Comment: @dariober `sudo pip3 install snakemake`

Comment: ahah! @GregGlockner know I know _why_ it calls Gurobi: `job_selector_ilp` "Job scheduling by optimization of resource usage by solving ILP using pulp"

Comment: If of any help, I installed snakemake with `pip3 install snakemake` (no sudo) and I can do `import pulp.apis.gurobi_api` without problems. I guess that would throw an error if there were issues with the license